# Move file in Azure Storage to shared network directory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, shared-directory, azure-storage-files

The workflow/function (calling it like that as I do not know how) should be in Azure.

Modern A application can write to Azure not to shared directory

Legacy B application can read from shared directory not Azure

1. A sends file to Azure
2. Azure sends file to shared directory

Is 2. possible?

Update:
I can use azcopy but I have to run it locally. Could I put this command into "something" in Azure that would run it at regular intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Using Azure File Storage, application A can store the data on a storage account (which lives on Azure), and also, application B can mount a network drive pointing to Azure File Storage.

Application A can upload a file like this (assuming it's using c#):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme

Application B will mount like this:

[image]

Comment: Application B cannot do this, don't ask why :)

The question is can Azure move the file to a network directory?

Comment: yes, but you`ll need to mount the network directory in a VM and also setup vpn to allow the communication between Azure and your on premises environment